# Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization in ios 9 with objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I'm trying to use MapKit on iOS 8 and I keep getting the error:

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call   
-[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager 
requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

Looking it up here, I found that I had to implement NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription in my plist but nothing happens and I still get that error in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

1.- Add the following lines to your info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>The spirit of stack overflow is coders helping coders</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>I have learned more on stack overflow than anything else</string>
```

2.- Prompt for location authorization:

```
 if ([self.locationManager  respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
               [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

3.-Update location when user have accepted...

```
   - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status{

        if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add those code in `CLLocationManager` initialization.

for example:
`@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;`
then in your implementation just call `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];` before calling the update function.

Answer (score 0):

after your `cllocationmanager` initilaisation check for ios 8 and ask for the permission

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];// [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    // Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
```

reference http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to implementing the keys in PList (I have `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescritpion` and `Privacy - Location Usage Description`), I solved the warning with the following code:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || status ==  kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    } else {
        _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    }
}
```